# I never finished my master's degree; how can I reflect the courses I took on my resume/CV?

Tags: cv

I completed some of the coursework for a master's degree in Hospital Administration, but I did not complete the entire program or graduate. Can I still include this coursework in my resume/CV? And if so, what should I write?

Comment: [This post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68814/graduate-coursework-not-taken-for-a-degree-still-relevant-for-graduate-admissio) and [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21467/graduate-courses-as-undergrad-vs-masters-degree?rq=1) are related and somewhat similar to yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graduate coursework not taken for a degree- still relevant for graduate admissions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68814/graduate-coursework-not-taken-for-a-degree-still-relevant-for-graduate-admissio)

Comment: It should not be reflected in your CV at all.  Writing "Master in Hospital Administration," no matter what the qualifier, is likely to cost you your job when your credentials are checked and it is found that you do not hold such a degree.

Comment: I've made some (perhaps too many?) edits to the question, since I'm of the opinion that it's subtlely but significantly different than the one @Coder pointed out. Please feel free to edit back if I made too many changes or changed the intent of the question.

Comment: @BobBrown: The question has meanwhile be changed, and as it stands now, "it should not be reflected (...) at all" seems too hard an advice. With that said, this is of course one of the reasons why it is useful to have degrees: Someone with a degree needs just a single line to write "Master in Hospital Administration", whereas the OP may need to spend a whole paragraph to outline the approximate fraction of the programme that they completed, successfully or partially before dropping out.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider something like this:

> **Education**
>
> Undergraduate Institution 
>  B.S. in DEGREE FIELD, August 2005-December 2010
>
> Graduate Institution 
>  Graduate-level coursework in Health
>   Administration, August 2016-May 2017

If you want, after the graduate level coursework line, you could list relevant classes. For instance:

> Relevant courses: Hospital Administration, Global Health Policy, ...

Comment: This looks like it would immediately prompt the question: "Ok, so when are you expecting to complete your graduate degree?"

Comment: Interesting, I think if that was what was being communicated I would write, "MPA in Health Administration, expected December 2018" or whatever. At least that is the convention in my field. I suppose you could put dates after the graduate level line: "2016-2017" I will edit to include.

Comment: I read the question in such a way that the OP does not intend to graduate any more. As such, the question I wrote in my comment above would be either a reason why the OP's application may be sorted out right from the start (because essential information is missing), or how the OP could be setting themselves up for a rather awkward moment during an interview (when being asked that exact question).

Comment: Absolutely. I don't think that OP is taking any more classes. The end date says that they have already stopped taking classes. I did my master's in a fairly practical field and this is a common occurrence. It would not surprise an employer that a person didn't pay for a full Master's degree. In an interview, the person would say that they learned a lot in the courses they took, but that they didn't feel it was worth the cost to continue. (Assuming they were not forcibly kicked out.)

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Where I live, cost is not a factor in education, so I did not consider the possibility anyone might actually intentionally take a partial degree for financial reasons (hence, "partial degree" sounded equivalent to me to "kicked out/left in time before he'd get kicked out"), but it sounds like a realistic thing to do in the context of tuition fees.